# Remove prefix and suffix text of a token string

Tags: javascript

I am here to ask your help, and this is my problem:

I have created a token inside a text editor, and then select the token to edit it. But what I am afraid is that the text selected do not contain only the token but contains other extra text. So what I am going to ask is how can I remove the extra text before and after the token? I will provide an example of the token structure for you to understand my idea.

This is the value of token: 
`[[Token: there is some text]]`

The token contain text inside "[[" and "]]" including the quotation marks!

That is what the token should be when selected, but what if the user not selected only the token string within the text, but also selected the whole text that contains the token?

This an example for that situation:

```
prefixtext[[Token: there is some text]]suffixtext
```

Finally, I want to remove the prefix text and suffix text from the token to keep the token only when it selected from the text editor.

Please using java script for solving this issue, and please assume that I am already got the text that contains token from text editor!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str="Visit Microsoft!";
var n=str.replace("Microsoft","W3Schools");
```

Try `replace` method

Try using regex like something this

```
var txt='prefixtext[[Token: there is some text]]suffixtext';

      var re1='.*?';    // Non-greedy match on filler
      var re2='(\\[.*?\\])';    // Square Braces 1

      var p = new RegExp(re1+re2,["i"]);
      var m = p.exec(txt);
      if (m != null) {
         var sbraces1=m[1];
         document.write("("+sbraces1.replace(/</,"&lt;")+")"+"\n");
      }
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jgCEb/1/)

Comment: Sorry, but how do I know exactly what the prefix and suffix text could be if the token selected from other user (not me)?

Comment: Agreed, it's not this simple

Comment: @user1145009 *that's exactly what the OP is trying to find out how to do*

Comment: Yest! I could using sub string or cut string from javascript. But that is an odd way, and I don't want to do that. There is a good way to do that in javascript is using "RegExp". But I'm very sorry that I am not have mush knowledge in "RegExp".

Comment: Added a rwgex try that

Comment: Did you mean this: `var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + token + '=([^&#]*)');`

Comment: @TriNguyenDung - I don't see any advantage to using a regular expression here.  Using `String.substring()` and `String.indexOf()` would be more straightforward and efficient.  Find the token in the string using `indexOf()` and remove the head and tail with `substring()`...

Comment: That was an odd way as I said! But don't force yourself in this too much. I am always have my respect for anyone has involved on my issue.

Comment: @TriNguyenDung Have u checked fiddle

Comment: I did check that. I am sorry for this late which because I was busy with my work at company. Thank you too much, your code work well for this issue.